# Store not updated in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In the "Favorite List" reducer

I have two helper function "Add/Remove" item from the array

the Add work well but Remove it does not update the store in the actual time, because I have a checker in my UI that checks if this song_id in the array or not and bassed on it I update the heart icon BUT it does not work well when I dispatch the remove Action, **In Other Words** "*Not Re-render the component*"!.

**Action File**

```
import {ADD_TO_FAVORITE, REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE} from './types';

export const addToFavoriteFunction = track_id => {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_FAVORITE,
    payload: track_id,
  };
};

export const removeFromFavoriteFunction = track_id => {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE,
    payload: track_id,
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
import {ADD_TO_FAVORITE, REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE} from '../actions/types';

let initialState = [];

const addSongFav = (songs, songId, flag) => {
  if (songs.some(song => song.track_id === songId)) {
    return songs;
  } else {
    let isFav = {track_id: songId, isFavorite: flag};
    return [...songs, isFav];
  }
};

const removeSongFav = (songs, songId) => {
  const newState = songs.filter(song => song.track_id !== songId);
  return newState;
};


const isFavoriteReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {payload, type} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TO_FAVORITE: {
      return addSongFav(state, payload, true);
    }
    case REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE:
      return removeSongFav(state, payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default isFavoriteReducer;
```

**"Music Player Component"**

```
 ....
 checkFavorite = () => {
    let {currentTrackIndex, tunes} = this.state;
    console.log(tunes[currentTrackIndex].id);
    let id = tunes[currentTrackIndex].id;
    let songs = this.props.favorite;
    let isFavorite = songs.some(song => song.track_id === id);
    this.setState({isFavorite});
  };

componentDidMount() {
    this.checkFavorite();
  }



  addToFavorite = async () => {
    const {tunes, token, currentTrackIndex} = this.state;
    this.setState({isFavorite: true});
    let id = tunes[currentTrackIndex].id;
    try {
      this.props.addToFavoriteAction(id);
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: AuthStr,
      };
      //  here i send a hit the endoint
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({isFavorite: false});
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


deleteFromFavorite = async () => {
    const {tunes, token, isFavorite, currentTrackIndex} = this.state;
    let id = tunes[currentTrackIndex].id;
    this.props.removerFromFavoriteAction(id);
    try {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: AuthStr,
      };
      // here i send a hit the endoint
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };



<Button onPress={() => this.state.isFavorite
                  ? this.deleteFromFavorite()
                  : this.addToFavorite()} >
  <Icon name={this.state.isFavorite ? 'favorite' : 'favorite-border'} />
</Button>

....

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    incrementCount: count => {
      dispatch(incrementCount(count));
    },

    addToFavoriteAction: track_id => {
      dispatch(addToFavoriteFunction(track_id));
    },

    removerFromFavoriteAction: track_id => {
      dispatch(removeFromFavoriteFunction(track_id));
    },
  };
};

mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    favorite: state.favorite,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MusicPlayer);
```

Comment: You only call `checkFavorite` after the component mounted, do you call it anywhere else? Updating redux store state probably isn't calling a remount of your component.

Comment: @AndyRay hmm, No I don't call it in anywhere else

Comment: can you include your definitions of `this.deleteFromFavourite()` & `this.addToFavourite()`?

Comment: @DanPantry I Added it, check again!

Comment: When you remove a song from favorites, you should set the property `isFavorite: false` for the song item.

Comment: @Hoyen yes... that's will solve it I know, but my question is why I can't re-render component or something after dispatch the Action  So I want to know if my functions helper do the job right or not

Comment: @DanPantry Any update? 

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see how you are using Redux in your component at all. you're not dispatching any actions to the reducer

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong with your code with-out seeing everything (e.g. mapDispatchToProps & your Redux store). Maybe you could create a minimal example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). Have you checked that `REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE` action is dispatched? You can test this by adding a `console.log` or `debugger;` to `isFavoriteReducer` in `case REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE:`.

Comment: @DanPantry I added the dispatching code, Can you check again?

Comment: @AWolf Sorry, But it's a react-native project! And i add more details, can you check it again! And yes when i run the debugger I can see the dispatch action and it's removing the item from the favorite list But my whole issue it's not updating the icon heart in the component So that's the issue

Comment: Hey, @AWolf I make some mini example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/redux-player) check it and let me know, please!

Comment: Hey, @DanPantry I add some [demo](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/redux-player) on snack, can you please check it?

Comment: Hey @OliverD, I believe you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of `componentDidMount`. However, I wonder why you are handling the `isFavorite` logic inside the component, instead of having a selector do it.

Comment: Hey @FedericoAlecci hmm, What is `selector`? I'm new in redux hah :) and I don't hear about `getDerivedStateFromProps` before can u check [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/05/23/react-v-16-4.html#bugfix-for-getderivedstatefromprops) !

Comment: Glad someone gave you the answer! :)

Comment: Hey @FedericoAlecci, can u give me an example about the selector in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the live demo, it helped a lot to see the whole picture. The issue is that **your view is not actually using the values in your Redux store at all**. The reducer is fine and everything is working behind the scenes, but take a look...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    favorite: state,
  };
};
```

This is your `mapStateToProps` method, and `favorite` contains an array of the favorite tracks that is successfully being updated whenever you dispatch an action. The reason why your view is not updated accordingly is that you're not using this array anywhere.

```
<Icon
  style={{color:"#00f"}}
  type="MaterialIcons"
  name={this.state.isFavorite ? 'favorite' : 'favorite-border'}
/>
```

In this piece of code, **what you're checking is the value of a `isFavorite` property inside of your component's inner state**. The reason why it works when you add a favorite is because you're calling `setState` at the beginning of `addToFavorite`. On the contrary, `deleteFromFavorite` is missing that `setState` call, which is the reason your icon is not changing.

If you want to use what you have in the Redux store to determine which icon to show, **you should change your code so it uses `this.props.favorite`**, which is the property that actually references the store and changes according to your actions.

```
const isCurrentTrackFavorite = () => {
  const { tunes, currentTrackIndex } = this.state;
  const currentTrackId = tunes[currentTrackIndex].track_id;

  // Check array in the Redux store to see if the track has been added to favorites
  return this.props.favorite.findIndex(track => track.track_id === currentTrackId) != -1;
};

render() {
  <Icon
    style={{color:"#00f"}}
    type="MaterialIcons"
    name={isCurrentTrackFavorite() ? 'favorite' : 'favorite-border'}
  />
}
```

By making this change, your component will be really listening to the contents of the store and should update the view whenever the array of favorites changes.

Comment: Can you share the editable code on a snack? I'm facing issues like this!

Comment: GREAT, Thank you <3 I understood it now, really thanks